PowerPoint Slide Count Using Excel Power Query Using Get Data From Folder
How do I get the total slide count across multiple PowerPoint presentations? I have a folder with ~100 PowerPoint files and I'm curious to know the combined slide count.
I used Excel Power Query >> Get Data >> From Folder, but I can find the attribute for slide count.
I can see the data if I view the properties using file explorer and selecting "Details" then scroll down to the "Content" area.
Is there a way to export this information to Excel using Power Query?

I used Excel Power Query >> Get Data >> From Folder, but I can find the attribute for slide count.

Is there a way to create a custom column and retrieve this information?

You will have to use VBA to open each file and retrieve the number of slides.

I'm not an expert in VBA, do you know what VBA code I could reference to achieve this?

ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

does this work if I have a list of file paths in an excel file and I want to add a column that shows the slide count?

Each ppt-file has to be open to retrieve the number of slides! I don't think you can do that without VBA
